# weblink implementation in iphone application

Tags: iphone, ios

I want to implement a web link in my application and this link should not go out of the application it must open inside the application.

Anyone has solution for it?

Comment: "go out of the application it must open inside the application." what you mean saying this ?

Comment: Normally we see if we put link on view and click on it then it open on safari or webview and go out of application not remain inside the application.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Three20](http://github.com/joehewitt/three20) `TTStyledText` class.

Answer (score 0):

Create a webview and load the url inside the webview.

```
UIWebView *webview = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
    [self.view addSubview:webview];
[webview loadRequest:
[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:
[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"]]];
```